# Unable to execute Python script from PHP shell_exec

Tags: php, python

I'm trying to execute a python (Python 3) script from the PHP `shell_exec`function but it doesn't seem to be working, I'm trying it on a windows system but it will be in CentOS 7 in production.

In the below code snippet nothing happens when the PHP runs. But it I use the `$response = shell_exec("php -v");` line it displays the PHP version ok. I've also tried running the python script directly on the command line and it runs fine with no errors.

**Code**

```
    $command = "\"C:\Programs\Python\Python36-32\python.exe\" \"E:\\htdocs\\dev\\_nodes\\jobs\\jobCheck.py\" \"https:/www.google.ie\" 1";
    $response = shell_exec($command);
    //$response = shell_exec("php -v");
    echo $response;
```

**Command Line**

```
"C:\Programs\Python\Python36-32\python.exe" "E:\\htdocs\\dev\\_nodes\\jobs\\jobCheck.py" "https:/www.google.ie" 1
```

**Update #1**

I've gotten the python script to run via PHP, but the python script crashes once it hits `driver = webdriver.PhantomJS()`, the import exists in the python script `from selenium import webdriver` and all this functionality works fine once called directly via the command line but doesn't seem to work once the python script is called from PHP.

Here's a sample script that prints out `test 1` but not `test 2` when called from the PHP script.

```
from selenium import webdriver

print("test 1")

driver = webdriver.PhantomJS()

print("test 2")

driver.quit()
```

**Update #2**

Looks like it was an issue with paths, there is a file created in the python script that was using a relative path, once I changed the path to be a full path the script ran ok both in the command line and when being called via the PHP script.

Comment: make sure from your `jobCheck.py` permissions :) php apache sapi is running under www-data user, which is often have no permissions to perform your scripts;

Comment: @hassan, even on a windows system?

Comment: Are you sure that the dir is right?

Comment: @getl0st, yes, it works fine when when run via a command prompt.

Comment: Can you run any other command?

Comment: @getl0st, I've tried `php -v` and it works fine and displays the PHP version information.

Comment: Try to exec python version

Comment: I'd recommend setting up a vagrant instance with centos 7 so that your development system more closely. Barring that, what is the output of the python script supposed to be? Is null being returned?

Comment: @Jaime, its generating an empty JSON file., there is a message returned from the python script when run on the command line but when called via PHP the JSON isn't created and no message is returned to the PHP script.

Comment: Gotten a bit further, looks like `webdriver` is causing the python script to crash when called from the PHP script.

Comment: Looks like it was a combination of things, there was a permission issue but this looks to have been caused by a full directory path not being used in the python script, I was using a relative path, once I changed it to a full path it seems to all be working ok now.

Answer (score -1):

You need to scape the command string.

Try using `escapeshellarg` function.

```
$command = escapeshellarg('C:\Programs\Python\Python36-32\python.exe "E:\htdocs\dev\_nodes\jobs/jobCheck.py" "https:/www.google.ie" 1');
$response = shell_exec($command);
//$response = shell_exec("php -v");
echo $response;
```

http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.escapeshellarg.php

Comment: Tried this, still nothing.